# Recursion: Solving an imported maze?

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, stack, maze

I'm working on a maze and am stuck. Using JFileChooser, I can import and read into the maze in a .txt file, where a series of spaces and hashtags determine paths and walls. `String path = " ";` and `String wall = "#";`

This is the method as of now doing everything:

```
@Override
    public void readMaze() throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        int row;
        int col;

        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        Scanner in = null;

        if (chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        {
        File selectedFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();
        in = new Scanner(selectedFile);

        /*READ FILE*/
        Scanner readLine = new Scanner (new FileReader(selectedFile));

        col = readLine.nextInt();//first reading
            System.out.println(col);
        row = readLine.nextInt(); //second reading
            System.out.println(row);

        Array[][] array = new Array[row][col];

        do
        {
            String i = readLine.nextLine();

            //System.out.println(i);

            for (int j = 0; j < i.length(); j++)
            {
                String compare = i.substring(j, j+1);

                if(compare.equals(wall))
                {
                    //Do nothing, see if there's a path adjacent.
                    System.out.println("Wall");
                }
                if(compare.equals(path))
                {
                    System.out.println("Path");
                    //Check for additional paths.
                        // don't if explored
                        //else explore
                }
            }

        } while(readLine.hasNextLine() == true);

        readLine.close();

        }

    }
```

This is our interface as of now, if it matters:
public interface lab3MVCInterface

```
{
    enum direction {N, S, E, W};

    void readMaze() throws FileNotFoundException;
    void solveMaze();

    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    Scanner in = null;

    String wall = "#";
    String path = " ";
    void readMaze(JFileChooser chooser, Scanner in)
            throws FileNotFoundException;


}
```

But we don't have any clue how to determine how to determine if there's a path or not. This is a class assignment, so I'm not looking for answers, but I would appreciate pointers in the right direction on a proper approach. For the assignment, we can use recursion or stacks to complete it... we decided on recursion since stacks was a nightmare on our end.

Thank you for your assistance!! :) I know in the past I have not followed through with threads, but I AM making an effort to update them (I locked myself out of the email, after losing the password for my account. Go figure) as we speak!

Edit: Here's a sample of code opened from a .txt file:
(The first number sets the array[col][] value, the second sets the array[][row] value for sizing.)

```
7
7
#######
    ###
### ###
### ###
#      
### ###
#######
```

Comment: I suggest looking at the hits for ["maze solving algorithm"](https://www.google.com/search?q=maze+solving+algorithm&oq=maze+solving+algorithm&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.4669j0j7&client=ubuntu-browser&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8). The first two look promising.

Comment: Do you have a sample file?  The first thing is to work out your starting point, you could then use a "left-hand" rule, basically, always follow the wall to your left.  You will need a method which can take a direction and determine if it can move or not, if it can't it rotates 90 degrees and calls itself with the new direction...

Comment: I have to use the mazes as-is, my professor didn't make a starting point, so I can't add anything to create a start and ending point. I'm just assuming that we're starting in one of the top corners when a space is first available. I don't think we have to go through the whole maze, and we don't have to have it as "shortest route", it just needs to be solved.Code-Apprentice, I clicked the link and Wikipedia's result helped me get a fairly decent grasp. I'll admit I'm a little behind on this assignment due to a reading disability, so my skills aren't as sophisticated as others.

Comment: I can only do so much at a time, which is why I REALLY don't understand sophisticated code too well. I'm hoping for a more simple explanation.

Comment: @MadProgrammer, I wondered if there was something like that existent! How would you propose that procedure?

Comment: This is silly... but how do I add to an array? array[row][col].add(col); does not work. It complains that "The Method add(int) is undefined for the type Array". What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I don't think `Array[][]` is the right datatype to use for a 2D array of characters.  Maybe you could use a `char[][]` instead, since each element will be either `' '` or `'#'`.

Secondly, what you could do is start at the "entry" point of the maze, and change the `' '` to `'.'` to indicate "I can get here"; then change every `' '` to `'.'` if it's adjacent to a `'.'`.

Lather, rinse and repeat, until you EITHER reach the end point, OR run out of characters to change to `'.'` (in which case the maze is impossible).

Comment: The breadcrumb idea (changing the PATH " " to TRIED"." is a good idea. It'd also help with tracking. But what about cases where it's in an intersection with 2+ possible paths? I'll definitely make that char[][] change, thank you! :) David Wallace

Comment: It's OK at an intersection.  Remember,  you mark everything next to a dot with another dot.  So if there's an intersection, your line of dots spreads out in every possible direction.  Note that this method doesn't solve the maze for you - it only tells you that there's a solution; which is what you asked.

Comment: Aah! I get it now! I talked to my professor further, and he said the exact same thing you were. I was confused on how to backtrack in the maze. He explained there are a series of numbers under the sample maze he provided, the first 2 are the coordinants for array[row][], and the second for array[][col], telling me the starting point and the ending point. Intersections confused me, he your method is right, but to keep track of intersections (what path(s) I took) by storing intersections into the array and popping them when they aren't needed. Thank you David!!!

Comment: Alright....I just realized this isn't adding into the array. How do I store what is being read into the array?

Comment: I tried trading it out for a second time with an ArrayList, and this time it doesn't complain but throws an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds error when ran. I'l figure this part out.... Thanks everyone!

Comment: OK, @HowbeitGirl good luck, and feel free to comment again if you need more help.  Sorry that I haven't been online for the last couple of days to see your earlier comments here.

Comment: You're good David Wallace, you've been a tremendous help! Trading it to a char[][] array made it functional... now we just need to load what's being read into the array.

Comment: No problem @HowbeitGirl - glad that you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can easily be transformed into graph traversal problem. Imagine each "path" point of the maze as a vertex of the graph and add an edge between two vertices if and only if they are directly adjacent in the maze. After that you can use BFS or DFS algorithms to find if there is a path from the start vertex of the maze to the end vertex.
If using BFS you don't even have to explicitly build the graph, the 2D array of the maze will do. For each vertex you can go in 4 directions, check if it is not out of bounds and is accessible (is a space character), check if you visited it already and if not add it to the queue.

Hope this gives you enough pointers to do further research.